# Making hidden files appear in FTP window (connecting to Linux server outside Terminal)

Tags: macos, finder, network, ftp

This feels so trivial but I've learned a Linux system I've used remotely for years may be shutting down and I'm anxious to move all of my files off of it.  I've connected to it by opening a MacOS connection (Go -> Connect to Server) but I have long forgotten the correct prefix to the URL so I've been using ftp:// of late.  However, this option does not show any hidden files (prefixed with a "."), and a link to my web directory is also not visible.  Any assistance in either connecting properly or seeing these additional files/directories would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Finder you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to toggle hidden folders/files. Often their name is prefixed with a `.`.

If that doesn't show any additional folders, best would be to use a command line tool, such as [`rsync`](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/45185-mac-101-learn-the-power-of-rsync-for-backup-remote-archive-systems/), to get all the files from your remote Linux machine onto your Mac.